# Is there any way to download a CSV report using newman which will include console.log data

Tags: report, postman, newman

Is there any way to download a CSV report using newman which will include console.log data. I am able to generate html report which includes the console.log data there but would like to know if there is a such possibility for CSV reports as well.
Thanks much

Comment: There is an awesome csv reporter available for Newman but this currently doesn't show the console logs. I added the logs to the HTML reporter as an experiment, it was something that wasn't part of any of reporter (that I know of).

Comment: @DannyDainton thanks for your reply, yes I know that html reports include the console.log data just would like to know if console.log data could be included in csv reports as well, but seems no by this time.

Comment: I meant that when I created the HTML reporter, I added the capability to show the console log statements from Newman. I did that because no other custom reporter had the ability to do that. You could fork the csv reporter and try and add that in, they are open source. https://github.com/matt-ball/newman-reporter-csv